# Spring boot custom auto configuration for entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot project which consists of multiple smaller projects. They all share a common project which consists of helper classes and such. On this common project I'm trying to create a `Service`, `Repository`, `Entity` and a `Controller` which could be shared and selectively enabled along of all other projects (debug endpoints with persisted data, each project has a separate database).

I'm thinking the ideal solution for this is to create a configuration bean which should be defined in order to enable these features or something along those lines.

At the moment I have this setup. Common entity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class SomeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    protected String name;

    public SomeEntity() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

The service defining common methods:

```
public abstract class SomeEntityService<T extends SomeEntity> {

    private final SomeRepository<T> someRepository;

    public SomeEntityService(SomeRepository<T> someRepository) {
        this.someRepository = someRepository;
    }

    public T getSomeEntity(String name) {
        return someRepository.findByName(name);
    }

    public List<T> getSomeEntities() {
        return someRepository.findAll();
    }

    public abstract void init();
}
```

Common controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/entities")
@ConditionalOnBean(value = SomeEntityService.class)
public class SomeController<T extends SomeEntity> {

    private final SomeEntityService<T> someEntityService;

    @Autowired
    public SomeController(SomeEntityService<T> someEntityService) {
        this.someEntityService = someEntityService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<T> getSomeEntities() {
        return someEntityService.getSomeEntities();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public T getSomeEntity(@PathVariable String name) {
        return someEntityService.getSomeEntity(name);
    }
}
```

Common repository:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface SomeRepository<T extends SomeEntity> extends JpaRepository<T, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {

    T findByName(String name);
}
```

The full project can be found [here](https://github.com/Edvinas01/AutoConfiguration).

Now in this example, if I implement `SomeService`, `SomeEntity` and `SomeRepository`, the controller bean gets created (notice the `@ConditionalOnBean` annotation on the controller) and everything works fine. However I do not want to redefine the entity and repository as all the needed implementation is already there, however I cannot find any documentation on how to disable the creation of these beans based on some conditions. So the questions would be:

- How can I disable the creation of specific `@Entity` annotated classes?
- How can I do the same for `@Repository` annotated classes?
- Is there a better way of doing this sort of thing?

**Edit:**

A more concrete question would be - how could I exclude selected entities from scanning based on some condition, is it possible to do this in spring?

For example, create a set of entities only is some specific bean is created or some property in application.properties file is defined.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `@ConditionalOnProperty` and configuring it through properties files?

[This](https://fbflex.wordpress.com/2014/10/08/spring-boot-recipe-turn-beans-on-and-off-by-setting-a-property/) article has the following to say:

> In Spring Boot, you can use the @ConditionalOnProperty annotation to enable or disable a particular bean based on the presence of a property. This is very useful if you want to provide optional features to your microservice.

Comment: It doesn't work on entities, if I annotate `SomeEntity` class and remove all the service declarations, the database table is still created.